# Unable to open anaconda navigator from any environment rather than base

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

I'm working on building a ChatBot following a tutorial where the instructor creates 2 virtual environments for tf 1.0.0(ChatBot) and tf 0.12.1(the_best_chatbot). I created both of them and previously on the base, I installed tf 2.1.0. Now the problem is, 
1.

```
fahim@Fahim:~$ conda activate ChatBot
(ChatBot) fahim@Fahim:~$ anaconda-navigator
anaconda-navigator: command not found
(ChatBot) fahim@Fahim:~$ conda deactivate

fahim@Fahim:~$ conda activate the_best_chatbot
(the_best_chatbot) fahim@Fahim:~$ anaconda-navigator
anaconda-navigator: command not found
(the_best_chatbot) fahim@Fahim:~$ conda deactivate

fahim@Fahim:~$ conda activate
(base) fahim@Fahim:~$ anaconda-navigator
  OpenType support missing for "Ubuntu", script 12
```

Only the base environment is working. 
2. Launched anaconda-navigator from the base env. From the "Applications on" drop down menu, selected ChatBot, then launched spyder. From there,

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

This returns 2.1.0 with some warning, where it should return 1.0.0

How do I solve these 2 problems?
OS: Linux Mint 19.3

Comment: If all you need is to open Spyder, can't you do that directly from the command line?

Comment: No, output is the same: spyder: command not found